# The more you learn, the more you are sad?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, happiness

I've read multiple times that if you learn more, you understand more seeing the reality of things causing a sadness all over you; is that real? Or is it that the more you know the more you are happy?

Comment: _And I gave my heart to know wisdom, and to know madness and folly: I perceived that this also is vexation of spirit. For in much wisdom is much grief: and he that increaseth knowledge increaseth sorrow_ Bible Ecclesiastes. And Ramana the advaita Vedanta master:  _There will come a time when one will have to unlearn all one has learned_

Comment: Keep learning and find out?

Comment: In favor of happiness: https://abstrusegoose.com/275

Comment: I would say it depends on _what_ specifically is learned.  Did one learn about something that is basically good, or basically bad?

Comment: Can you Post several examples of each idea, then explain why they all leave you sitting on the fence? Otherwise, isn'[t the Question really whether you think you should be sad or not? If that's the case, are you sad, or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any given piece of information can make you sad, but it can also make you happy.

Whether the sum of all knowledge makes you more happy or more sad would be hard to judge, especially given that every person is different and no-one knows everything.

More significantly, knowledge allows you to *improve* things. If you learn something that makes you sad, you can potentially do something to prevent future sadness or create future happiness (not only for yourself, but also for others).

If you learn that your house is on fire, that may make you sad (or panicked, perhaps, but close enough), but that could allow you to put out the fire and limit the damage, to prevent the future sadness of learning that your house entirely burnt down.

Comment: And when you learn that the house is on fire, and also learn about how people ignore that their house is on fire because it would require them to do something about it, and they really don't feel like leaving the party within to tackle the problem, then you realize that it is you who is now excluded from the party while the others are still having fun. Point is: Ignorance of big problems is bliss, knowledge of them is frustration. And there are much more big, troubling problems out there than most of us can cope with.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Some philosophers have found happiness in wisdom. There is a post-modern idea that learning leads to nihilism. Nihilism does not necessarily lead to depression, but it can in certain people at certain times. Is ignorance bliss? Charles Dickens said that the two greatest evils are ignorance and want (A Christmas Carol).